# function that calculates sum of proper divisors

Tags: c++, math

I encountered a problem on SPOJ that requires the user to calculate sum of divisors of a number (n) modulus with another number (m)

http://www.spoj.com/problems/HDEVIL/

While calculating if I use this function, SPOJ gives WA. I am unable to find problem with the function. Any Advice is welcome and appreciated.

```
int i=0;
ll prod=1;
while(seive[i]*seive[i]<=n)
{
    int p=seive[i],j=1;
    ll count=1;
    while(n%p==0)
    {
        count+=modpow(p,j,mod);
        j++;
        n/=p;
    }

    prod=((prod%mod)*(count%mod))%mod;
    i++;
}
if(n>1)
{
    prod*=n+1;
    prod%=mod;
}
```

Here prod is the final sum and seive[] stores the prime numbers and modpow is the power modulus function.

Comment: What language is your program? (Add a tag for that language). What type is "ll"? Can you give the COMPLETE program, including declarations for seive and whatever includes are necessary to define ll or modpow?

Comment: ya sorry about that. ll is long long int in C++.This is the complete program :http://ideone.com/fUZUIC

Answer (score 0):

Find the factors of *n*, then use the [Divisor Summatory Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) to compute the sum of the divisors of *n*, taking all products modulo *m*. In your problem *n* < 10<sup>9</sup>, so a simple factoring function based on trial division will probably be sufficient.

Ask questions if you need additional help.

Comment: Ya that's fine but I couldn't find a fault in my function to calculate the sum.
Any help in that would be great. :)